# HTTPS site is not loading in NGINX web server

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, bitnami

Below is my NGINX configuration. My website is deployed on AWS EC2 instance. I have checked the firewall settings and port 443 is open for public access.

I'm able to access my website from `http://example.com`. But I'm unable to access the website from `https://example.com`.

If I change the setting from `listen 443;` to `listen 443 ssl;`. I'm getting an error while restarting the NGINX service.

I have secured SSL certificate from AWS Certificate Manager.

Config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443;

    # listen 443 ssl; 


    root /opt/bitnami/apps/my_website;
    index index.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
```

I tried the command `sudo nginx -t`

Response:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Edit 2: Adding some more details: The config file mentioned previously is located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`

Here is the code for `nginx.conf` file located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
 user  nginx;
 worker_processes  1;

 error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
 pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


 events {
worker_connections  1024;
 }


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

# include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;
#include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;

}
```

Code for `conf.d` located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

```
../
./
default.conf
```

Comment: What does `nginx -t`? This should really be your first step if you have issues with your configuration...

Comment: @Ginnungagap I have added the response in Edit.

Comment: What is the actual error you get when you try to reach your site? `unable to access` is not helpful.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Im getting this error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT `

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have checked whether port is open using this tool - https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/. The 443 port is open.

Comment: Nevertheless a timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I have checked the security group settings in EC2 instance, port 443 access is enabled. What should be my approach to find the issue?

Comment: There can be a firewall directly on the server, on your client, or anywhere in between. Check from different locations to localize the problem.

Comment: You need to put `listen 443 ssl;` back in. Only then can you run `nginx -t` to determine what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check listeners are currently configured in load balancer and proper SSL Certificate is assigned to HTTPS Protocol in "Listner tab".

2) Check Loadbalancer Security group.

3) Check EC2 Instance Security group.

---

server {

listen 80;

server_name www.example.com;

root /path/to/web/dir;

index index.html index.htm;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' ) {

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

}

}